# Ecplise color files plugin?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to assign certain files a colour (much like OSX's Finder):
Such that opened editor's tabs are assigned the same colour -  (and maybe even the text editor's background

For instance if I am working with MVC, I could assign all the Models blue, all the Views Green, Mediators Yellow etc...

I can't find one, but it seems so natural/obvious to me I thought I'd better ask.

Else, does anyone else have problems visually grouping th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of...

Please have a look at [Andrei Loskutov](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/privat.html)'s [Extended VS presentation plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html) which, as its name suggests, is a Visual Studio skin for Eclipse.  It has some tab colouring features (although may be the one you describe).

On a general note Andrei's eclipse plugins have, since version 2.x, garnered a lot of well deserved praise...